# what happens when we use multiple thread groups under the same test plan?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

Usually when we use thread group we can set the threads(users) number and ramp up time. Now if we set ramp up time 0 and threads to 10, as far as I understand, Jmeter tries to make all the threads ready in 0 sec simultaneously.
But what happens when when we add another thread group with threads 20 and ramp up time.

1. Does all the 30 threads get ready in 0 sec ramp up?
2. If so, is it equivalent to one thread group with 30 threads and 0 sec ramp up time?

It would be really cool if someone can help me to clear the doubts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes

You can verify this yourself using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener (can be installed via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) as a part of **3 Basic Graphs** bundle)

[image]

or the equivalent chart of the JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image]

Normally people use more than one thread group when they need to simulate more than one group of i.e.  business users, for example you might want to mimic the following "populations":

- authenticated users which are doing some work
- not authenticated users which are logging in
- anonymous users who are wandering across the application
- admin users doing user management, approvals, moderations, etc.

If you have only one logical group of users it doesn't make sense to use more than one thread group